# matplotlib forcing pan/zoom to constrain to x-axes

Tags: python, matplotlib

Matplotlib has a feature where if you hold down the "x" or "y" keys it constrains panning or zooming to the corresponding axis.

**Is there a way to cause this to be the default?** For some reason my CPU does not allow touchpad movement when a letter key is held down. And I only want the x-axis to be pan/zoomed, not the y-axis.

---

edit: found the pan/zoom function at https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/axes.py#L3001

which contains an internal function `format_deltas`. But I have no idea how to override the Axes class with a subclass when Axes objects are created automatically from Figure objects.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is possible to use your own axes class. In your case you can inherit from `matplotlib.axes.Axes` and change the `drag_pan` method to always act as though the 'x' key is being pressed. However the zooming doesn't seem to be defined in that class. The following will only allow x axis panning:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    

class My_Axes(matplotlib.axes.Axes):
    name = "My_Axes"
    def drag_pan(self, button, key, x, y):
        matplotlib.axes.Axes.drag_pan(self, button, 'x', x, y) # pretend key=='x'

matplotlib.projections.register_projection(My_Axes)

figure = plt.figure()
ax = figure.add_subplot(111, projection="My_Axes")
ax.plot([0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 0])
plt.show()
```

For the zooming, you may have to look at the toolbar control itself. The [NavigationToolbar2](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/backend_bases.py#L2953) class has the `drag_zoom` method which seems to be what's relevant here, but tracking down how that works is quickly complicated by the fact that the different backends all have their own versions (e.g. [NavigationToolbar2TkAgg](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py#L789)

**edit**

You *can* monkeypatch the desired behaviour in:

```
import types
def press_zoom(self, event):
    event.key='x'
    matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg.NavigationToolbar2TkAgg.press_zoom(self,event)
figure.canvas.toolbar.press_zoom=types.MethodType(press_zoom, figure.canvas.toolbar)
```

You could do it properly and make a subclass of the toolbar, but you have to then create instances of Figure, FigureCanvas and your NavigationToolbar and put them in a Tk app or something. I don't think there's a really straightforward way to just use your own toolbar with the simple plotting interface.

Comment: sweet! I'll have to try it. The part I was having trouble with was the subclassing + how to hook it into add_subplot.

Comment: the "monkeypatch" approach almost worked, but somehow the assignment of the press_zoom method to individual instances doesn't stick (press zoom button, then unpress it, then press it again, now the zoom doesn't work). I got it to work by changing the __class__ method slot.

Comment: Hmm that sounds pretty weird, it doesn't seem to unstick for me though I haven't tested it very comprehensively. And I see your alternative using `_zoom_mode`, probably much more sensible than changing `event.key`

Answer (score 5):

simonb's approach worked but I had to tweak it for the `press_zoom` behavior, so that it keeps the `press_zoom` method a feature of the class, not the instance, but I added a hook to fixup the per-instance behavior.

```
import types

def constrainXPanZoomBehavior(fig):
    # make sure all figures' toolbars of this class call a postPressZoomHandler()
    def overrideZoomMode(oldZoom, target):
        def newZoom(self, event):
            oldZoom(self, event)
            if hasattr(self, 'postPressZoomHandler'):
                self.postPressZoomHandler()
        return newZoom
    def overrideToolbarZoom(fig, methodname, functransform, *args):
        toolbar = fig.canvas.toolbar
        oldMethod = getattr(toolbar.__class__, methodname)
        newMethod = functransform(oldMethod, toolbar, *args)
        setattr(toolbar.__class__, methodname, newMethod)
    overrideToolbarZoom(fig, 'press_zoom', overrideZoomMode)

    # for this specific instance, override the zoom mode to 'x' always
    def postPressZoomHandler(self):
        self._zoom_mode = 'x'
    fig.canvas.toolbar.postPressZoomHandler = types.MethodType(postPressZoomHandler, fig.canvas.toolbar)
    return fig
```